# Twilio SMS prefix in trial account

Tags: sms, twilio, message, prefix

I am trying to use the Twilio Java API to send messages. Using the trial account, I see a prefix is added to my message.

Can this prefix "Sent from your Twilio trial account" be removed/modified?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check to see if your question is [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: All you need to do is upgrade your account and the message prefixing it will go away. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is one easy way to remove the prefix in the SMS. [Just upgrade your account](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183208-Upgrading-to-a-paid-Twilio-account).

Once you have added a credit card or PayPal account and topped up your account with some money you will be able to send messages without the prefix and to any number you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Step 3 of Twilio

Upgrade your account in order to:

- Send messages and calls to unverified numbers
- Get more phone numbers
- Remove the trial message on calls and SMS
- Expand your international reach